How to use the result of Exercise 3 to prove $(j,k)=(i,j)(i,k)(i,j)$? ("Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake)
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
I checked $(j,k)=(i,j)(i,k)(i,j)$ holds when $i\neq j$ and $j\neq k$ and $k\neq i$.
The author wrote "cf. Exercise 3".
How to use the result of Exercise 3 to prove $(j,k)=(i,j)(i,k)(i,j)$?
My attempt:
$\sigma=(i,k)=(k_1,k_2)$.
$\tau=(i,j)$.
$\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(j,k)=(l_1,l_2)$.


$(i,j)$ is the transposition that exchanges $i$ and $j$.  Its inverse is itself.
Exercise $3$ says that to get $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ from $\sigma$, you replace each letter in the expression for $\sigma$ by its image under $\tau$.  In this case you replace the $i$ in $(i,k)$ by $j$, while $k$, which is neither $i$ nor $j$, is replaced by itself. Thus the result is $(j,k)$.

Robert Israel, thank you very much for your answer.
